# Why java.net.URLEncoder gives different result for same string?

Tags: java, url, encode

On the webapp server when I try encoding "`médicaux_Jérôme.txt`" using `java.net.URLEncoder` it gives following string:

```
me%CC%81dicaux_Je%CC%81ro%CC%82me.txt
```

While on my backend server when I try encoding the same string it gives following:

```
m%C3%A9dicaux_J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me.txt
```

Can someone help me understanding the different output for the same input? Also how can I get standardized output each time I decode the same string?

Answer (score 4):

The outcome depends on the platform, if you don't specify it.

See the [`java.net.URLEncoder` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

> `encode(String s)`
>
> **Deprecated**.
>
> The resulting string may vary depending on the platform's default encoding. Instead, use the `encode(String,String)` method to specify the encoding.

So, use the [suggested method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and specify the encoding:

```
String urlEncodedString = URLEncoder.encode(stringToBeUrlEncoded, "UTF-8")
```

---

About different representations for the same string, if you specified `"UTF-8"`:

The two URL encoded strings you gave in the question, although differently encoded, represent the same unencoded value, so there is nothing inherently wrong there. By writing both [in a decode tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), we can verify that they are the same.

This is due, as we are seeing in this case, to the fact that there are multiple ways to URL encode the same string, specially if they have acute accents (due to the [combining acute accent](http://www.charbase.com/0301-unicode-combining-acute-accent), precisely what happens in your case).

To your case, specifically, the first string encoded `é` as `e` + `´` ([latin small letter e](http://www.charbase.com/0065-unicode-latin-small-letter-e) + combining acute accent) resulting in `e%CC%81`. The second encoded `é` directly to `%C3%A9` ([latin small letter e with acute](http://www.charbase.com/00e9-unicode-latin-small-letter-e-with-acute) - two `%` because in UTF-8 it takes two bytes).

Again, there is no problem with either representation. Both are forms of [Unicode Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). It is known that Mac OS Xs tend to encode using the combining acute accent; in the end, it is a matter of preference of the encoder. In your case, there must be different JREs or, if that file name was user generated, then the user may have used a different OS (or tool) that generated that encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already specified UTF-8 encoding at both places!

Comment: Their VMs must be using different implementations, then. You see, the two URL encoded strings you gave, although differently encoded, represent the same unencoded value, so there is nothing inherently wrong there. Try writing both in [this online tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/). You'll see they are the same.

Comment: I understand that, and totally agree with what you are saying, but I am unable to understand what may be causing that issue, is there any why I can find that out?

Comment: Can you tell the VMs used in both environments?

Comment: By VM I mean JRE, are they the same version on both OSs? Are there any differences between the OSs (french locale vs english locale)? What originated the original (before encoding) strings? Were they on a database? File? User input? If an user originated them, do you know the user's OS?