# é becomes e ́ in Android

Tags: android

I am trying for Déjà to be used for my search query. using

```
URLEncoder.encode(searchKey, "UTF-8"));
```

it should give me D%C3%A9j%C3%A0, but giving me De%CC%81ja%CC%80

while I copy that 2 characters to notepad or browser. It becomes 1 character.

check Déjà and Déjà

both looks same but values are not the same. try copy, paste and delete characters.

Comment: you want to display it in textView or something like that?

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode('Déjà', "UTF-8")` returns `D%C3%A9j%C3%A0`. How did you introduce the value to be encoded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why java.net.URLEncoder gives different result for same string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550143/why-java-net-urlencoder-gives-different-result-for-same-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In unicode, there are many ways to represent the same characters.

For example `é` can be [LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm), or it can be `e` followed by [COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm). The utf-8 encoding for the former is `c3a9` while the latter is `cc81`.

The same story with `à`.

Normally this is not a problem. If you really need a specific unicode form, have a look at [`Normalizer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer).

Comment: (Old question without answer, got bumped up by an edit.)